# Overwriting Assetic\Extension\Twig\AsseticTokenParser::createNode is deprecated since 1.3. Overwrite AsseticTokenParser::createBodyNode instead

Tags: symfony, twig, assetic, twig-extension

I try to clean my app (Symfony 2.7.4) from all deprecated calls, but I can't find how to solve this deprecated call on my site. There is no documentation on this particular deprecated call.
Apparently, the warning occurs in the vendors so I have no clue.

```
DEPRECATED Overwriting Assetic\Extension\Twig\AsseticTokenParser::createNode is deprecated since 1.3.
Overwrite Assetic\Extension\Twig\AsseticTokenParser::createBodyNode instead.
```

If anyone has an idea on how to solve this deprecated call, please post your solution. Thanks

Comment: Which version of Symfony are you using?

Comment: I'am using Symfony 2.7.4

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because \Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\Twig\AsseticTokenParser from assetic-bundle is overwriting createNode instead of createBodyNode (it extends \Assetic\Extension\Twig\AsseticTokenParser). This is happening for me as well in symfony/assetic-bundle v2.3. Upgrade your version of symfony/assetic-bundle (2.7.1 is current stable release) and this should fix the problem. Assetic bundle requires v1.3 of kriswallsmith/assetic at v2.7.0.

Comment: My apologies, this is in the package symfony/assetic-bundle